# How to fix route issue in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I wanna make online quizzes with Laravel.
Two tables courses and questions connected to each other, the user can select from index page course name to go to quiz for that course, after submit it should go to questions.show, the id for the selected course pass also there.
But when I try to go to index page the error occurred as following:
""Undefined variable: course (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bilsan\resources\views\questions\index.blade.php)""

here is Questions index.blade:

```
     <form method="post" action="{{route('queations.show',$course->id)}}">
        @csrf  
        <select name="courses_id" id="courses_id" class="form-control mt-3" style="max-width:250px; margin:  auto;">
        <option>Select Courses</option>
            @foreach($courses as $course)
              <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->courses_name}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
  <div  class="mt-5 list-group" >
     <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="max-width:150px; margin: auto;">
  </div>

</form>
```

In questions controller :

```
      public function index()
{   
    $courses =Course::all();
    return view('questions.index',compact('courses'));
}
```

I use Laravel 7
 can any body help!!

Comment: You have a spelling mistake in the route name (queations should be questions).

Answer (score 2):

In your `<form>` you're trying to set a `course->id` for the route action, but `course` does not get defined until the foreach loop. Try to post it to a more general route (where it doesn't need a `course->id`) or make sure the view gets the `course` from the controller.

---

EDIT: My suggestions on your code

Add in your `QuestionsController`:

```
public function store() {
    $course = Course::findOrFail(request()->course_id);
    return view('questions.show', compact('course'));
}
```

Edit your form the `questions.index` view. I modified the action of the form, as I do not know what your routefile looks like. I assumed your controller is called QuestionsController. I also modified the name of the `select` to be `course_id` instead of `courses_id`.

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('QuestionsController@store')}}">
    @csrf  
    <select name="course_id" id="course_id" class="form-control mt-3" style="max-width:250px; margin:  auto;">
    <option>Select Courses</option>
        @foreach($courses as $course)
            <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->courses_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <div  class="mt-5 list-group" >
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="max-width:150px; margin: auto;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @DaliaNajeh Looking like you are trying the incorrect approach, which course you've selected from the drop-down, that `course->id` will be sent in your form post.

Comment: As @Stormhammer has said, the best way to handle this would be to point to a general route that just accepts a Request $request in the function, then you can do $course = Course::findorfail($request->courses_id)

Comment: Like Petay87 says, the best way to go about here (in my opinion) is to not require a `course id` in the route, and just make it general. You then use the code provided by Petay to find the selected course and send it to your questions.show view.

Comment: I change the form to <form method="post" action="{{route('questions.index')}}">  , this should go to the same page , but the an empty page appear.

Comment: Have you put a return on the controller to display a page?

Comment: I modified my answer, I think you would have everything you need now. If you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The form should go inside the `foreach` loop like this

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
<form method="post" action="{{route('questions.show',$course->id)}}">
    @csrf  
    <select name="courses_id" id="courses_id" class="form-control mt-3" style="max-width:250px; margin:  auto;">
    <option>Select Courses</option>
          <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->courses_name}}</option>

    </select>
    <div  class="mt-5 list-group" >
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="max-width:150px; margin: auto;">
    </div>
</form> 
@endforeach
```

In your question, blade doesnot know what $course is in your form route because the data that comes from the controller is $courses and the form also should be inside the loop so that $course variable is also defined in form action.

Comment: Although this would work, it would make the SELECT option pointless as it is only ever going to provide a single option for each course. This would work better if you use something like a card or button for each course to select.

Comment: This make drop down box and submit button for each option !!

Answer (score -1):

Make your `form` action to `route('question.store', $cource->id)`. The form need to submitted to store method followed by `resource` routing in web.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('queations.show',$course->id)}}">
    @csrf  
    <select name="courses_id" id="courses_id" class="form-control mt-3" style="max-width:250px; margin:  auto;">
    <option>Select Courses</option>
        @foreach($courses as $course)
          <option value="{{$course->id}}">{{$course->courses_name}}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
    <div  class="mt-5 list-group" >
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  style="max-width:150px; margin: auto;">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code as in the question and provide an additional help to the person asking the question.